# Reporte lento en procedimiento almacenado mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, mysql-cursores

Amigos tengo que hacer un reporte el cual comparo valores de un presupuesto mensual con con los valores reales del mismo mes.
Para esto cree un procedimiento donde saco todos los registros del presupuesto y los pongo en un cursos, en el bucle del cursos saco de uno en uno los valores reales de cada mes y los pongo en una tabla temporal y asi al final retorno todo lo que esta en esta tabla.

el codigo es el siguiente

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE sp_presupuesto(IN panio varchar(4))
    BEGIN
      DECLARE v_catctamaecon varchar(100);
      DECLARE v_nomcta varchar(200);
      DECLARE v_ctamaecon varchar(100);
      DECLARE v_ctacontpre varchar(100);
      DECLARE v_anopre varchar(4);
      DECLARE v_valpre0 numeric;
      DECLARE v_valpre1 numeric;
      -- ....
      DECLARE v_rene numeric;
      DECLARE v_rfeb numeric;
      DECLARE v_id integer;
      
      
      declare cur_presupuesto 
      cursor for
          select catctamaecon,nomcta,ctamaecon,
                    ctacontpre,anopre,valpre0,valpre1,valpre2,valpre3,valpre4,valpre5,valpre6,valpre7,valpre8,valpre9,valpre10,valpre11
          from maecon,maepre 
          where (catctamaecon like '4%' or  catctamaecon like '5%' ) and ctacontpre=ctamaecon
            and anopre=panio  order by ctamaecon ASC;
            
      declare continue HANDLER for not found set done = true;
    
      CREATE temporary TABLE tmppresupuestos(
          preid int,
          tipo varchar(50),
          precod varchar(100),
          precue varchar(200),
          ene numeric,feb numeric,mar numeric,abr numeric,may numeric,jun numeric,jul numeric,ago numeric,sep numeric,oct numeric,nov numeric,dic numeric,tot numeric,primary key(preid)
      );
      
      set total = 0;
      set v_id = 1;  
      
      open cur_presupuesto;
      loop1:loop
          FETCH cur_presupuesto INTO v_catctamaecon,v_nomcta,v_ctamaecon,v_ctacontpre,v_anopre,v_valpre0,v_valpre1,v_valpre2,v_valpre3,v_valpre4,v_valpre5,v_valpre6,v_valpre7,v_valpre8,v_valpre9,v_valpre10,v_valpre11;
          if done then
                 leave loop1;
          end if;
          -- inserto los valores del presupuesto
        
      set total = v_valpre0+v_valpre1+v_valpre2+v_valpre3+v_valpre4+v_valpre5+v_valpre6+v_valpre7+v_valpre8+v_valpre9+v_valpre10+v_valpre11;
      
      insert into tmppresupuestos( preid,tipo,precod,precue,ene,feb,mar,abr,may,jun,jul,ago,sep,oct,nov,dic,tot)
      values (v_id,'Pres',v_ctamaecon,v_nomcta,v_valpre0,v_valpre1,v_valpre2,v_valpre3,v_valpre4,v_valpre5,v_valpre6,v_valpre7,v_valpre8,v_valpre9,v_valpre10,v_valpre11,total);
        set v_id = v_id+1;
      -- inserto los valores reales

      set v_rene:=(select ifnull(sum(valorhis),0) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=v_ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=1 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1');
      set v_rfeb:=(select ifnull(sum(valorhis),0) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=v_ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=2 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1');
      set v_rmar:=(select ifnull(sum(valorhis),0) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=v_ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=3 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1');
      set v_rdic:=(select ifnull(sum(valorhis),0) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=v_ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=12 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1');
      ....
      ....
      set total = v_rene+v_rfeb+v_rmar+v_rabr+v_rmay+v_rjun+v_rjul+v_rago+v_rsep+v_roct+v_rnov+v_rdic;
      
      
      insert into tmppresupuestos( preid,tipo,precod,precue,ene,feb,mar,abr,may,jun,jul,ago,sep,oct,nov,dic,tot)
      values (v_id,'Real',v_ctamaecon,v_nomcta,v_rene,v_rfeb,v_rmar,v_rabr,v_rmay,v_rjun,v_rjul,v_rago,v_rsep,v_roct,v_rnov,v_rdic,total);
      set v_id = v_id+1;
      
    end loop loop1;
    close cur_presupuesto;
    
    select * from tmppresupuestos;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmppresupuestos;

END
```

Pero al ejecutarlo va demasiado lento se demora en ejecutar mas o menos 2 minutos con 30 segundos y de lo que veo es por los selects que hago para sacar os valores reales.

Pero la duda surge porque el reporte de lo hace de la misma forma desde php, se saca los datos del presupuesto, luego de uno en uno cada cuenta se abre la conexion y se consulta el valor real de cada cuenta con el mismo select. y al hacerlo asi no se demora ni 40 segundos.

entonces no se si es la forma correcta de hacer lo que necesito  hay alguna otra forma que sea mas eficiente

---

con el procedimiento que hice obtengo algo como esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
con lo que tu me sugieres obtendria algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces no pueso mostrar la fila de valores reales en la parte de abajo del presupuesto, por eso queria hacerlo con la tabla temporal.

Comment: Para diagnosticar problemas de desempeño se requiere la estructura de las tablas incluyendo índices. Un [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) es deseable.

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas:

- ¿Para qué necesitas la tabla temporal? Si es por extraer unos datos calculados, en la proyección (un humilde SELECT) uno puede incluir como columna campos calculados.
- ¿Para qué necesitas el cursor? Hacer las cosas registro por registro es lento y desaprovecha el poder del motor de BD. Puedes hacer `INSERT INTO tabla SELECT algo FROM otra_tabla` (sintaxis depende de cada motor) y el motor lo va a resolver; no debes usar el modelo mental de PHP o de otro código ajeno al motor que va fila por fila, el motor de BD puede hacer estas operaciones entre tablas y la implementación más o menos estándar de SQL lo permite.
- Dependiendo de cómo te conectes a la BD, las tablas temporales sólo viven [mientras la sesión está activa](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html). Si cierras la sesión en BD tras ejecutar el procedimiento, la tabla igual va a desaparecer.

Así pues, ese código dentro del procedimiento sería simplemente algo parecido a

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_presupuesto(IN panio varchar(4))
BEGIN

select 
 catctamaecon, 
 nomcta, 
 ctamaecon,
 ctacontpre,
 (select 
     ifnull(sum(valorhis),0) 
     FROM movcon 
     WHERE ctahiscon=TABLA1.ctamaecon 
     and MONTH(fechahis)=1 
     and year(fechahis)=panio 
     and db1cr2his='1'
  ) v_rene,
... 
v_valpre0+v_valpre1+v_valpre2+v_valpre3+v_valpre4+v_valpre5+v_valpre6+v_valpre7+v_valpre8+v_valpre9+v_valpre10+v_valpre11 total
from 
 maecon TABLA1, maepre 
where 
 (catctamaecon like '4%' or  catctamaecon like '5%' ) 
 and ctacontpre=ctamaecon
 and anopre=panio  
order by ctamaecon ASC;

END
```

Si tienes filas con sumas de campos de la tabla origen (la que usabas en el cursor), pues haz la suma; el motor va a agarrar cada fila, va a calcular la suma y chan, a la proyección (al resultado del select).

Así pues, sin cursor, sin tabla temporal. Un select. Y pues, matar ese select sobre la tabla temporal del final..

Comment: Gracas por tu respuesta,  pero al hacer de la forma que indicas, tendira algo asi  cuenta, vpresupuesto1, vreal1, vpresupuesto2, vreal2........ y lo que quiero es tener todo lo del presupuesto en una fila y abajo de esa todo lo qie es real algo asi primera fila cuenta1, vpresupuesto1vpresupuesto2,.......
segunda fila cuenta1,vreal1, vreal2.......

Comment: @fsigu me estás hablando de detalles de tu modelo como si yo los supiera. Haz de cuenta que no sé ;) Pon datos de prueba en tu pregunta (no necesariamente reales pero sí realistas) y muéstranos qué debería salir.